# Unable to read tags in m4p file in swift

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I have swift code that reads mp3/m4a file tags that works fine, but will not completely read all tags in m4p file. I am assuming this is due to DRM protection. Is there a way around this? I can see the tags but am unable to use AVFoundation to access the tags. Any ideas? These are my own files I purchased via itunes. Here is the function to read m4p files. Appreciate any help. Thanks!

```
func readM4p(line: String) -> String  {
        
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: line.removingPercentEncoding!)
        let filename = url.lastPathComponent
        let fileext = url.pathExtension
        var filesize = 0
        var title = ""
        var artist = ""
        var album = ""
        var track = ""
        var genre = ""
        var composer = ""
        var duration = ""
        var audioDict = [String: String]()
        
        audioDict["Path"] = line.removingPercentEncoding
        audioDict["FileName"] = filename
        audioDict["FileExt"] = fileext
        
        let avasset = AVAsset(url: url)

        let metadata = avasset.metadata(forFormat: AVMetadataFormat.iTunesMetadata)

        let types = avasset.availableMetadataFormats
 
        if ((types.isEmpty) || (types[0].rawValue != "com.apple.itunes") || (types[0].rawValue != "org.mp4ra")) {
            audioDict["TagType"] = ""
        } else {
            audioDict["TagType"] = types[0].rawValue
        }
        
        //(avasset.hasProtectedContent) ? print("Has Protected Content") : print("Has NO Protected Content")
        
        if let fs = url.fileSize {

            filesize = fs
            audioDict["FileSize"] = String(filesize)
        } else {
            audioDict["FileSize"] = ""
        }
        
        let titleItems = AVMetadataItem.metadataItems(from: metadata, withKey: "@nam", keySpace: AVMetadataKeySpace(rawValue: "itsk"))
        if let data = titleItems.first, let titleString = data.stringValue {
            title = titleString
            audioDict["Title"] = title
        } else {
            audioDict["Title"] = ""
        }
        
        let artistItems = AVMetadataItem.metadataItems(from: metadata, withKey: "©ART", keySpace: AVMetadataKeySpace(rawValue: "itsk"))
        if let data = artistItems.first, let artistString = data.stringValue {
            artist = artistString
            audioDict["Artist"] = artist
        } else {
            audioDict["Artist"] = ""
        }
        
        let albumItems = AVMetadataItem.metadataItems(from: metadata, withKey: "©alb", keySpace: AVMetadataKeySpace(rawValue: "itsk"))
        if let data = albumItems.first, let albumString = data.stringValue {
            album = albumString
            audioDict["Album"] = album
        } else {
            audioDict["Album"] = ""
        }
        
        let trackItems = AVMetadataItem.metadataItems(from: metadata, withKey: "trkn", keySpace: AVMetadataKeySpace(rawValue: "itsk"))
        if let data = trackItems.first, let trackData = data.dataValue {
            let str = String(trackData[3])
            track = str
            audioDict["Track"] = track
        } else {
            audioDict["Track"] = ""
        }
        
        let genreItems = AVMetadataItem.metadataItems(from: metadata, withKey: "©gen", keySpace: AVMetadataKeySpace(rawValue: "itsk"))
        if let data = genreItems.first, let genreString = data.stringValue {
            genre = genreString
            
        } else {
            let genreItems1 = AVMetadataItem.metadataItems(from: metadata, withKey: "gnre", keySpace: AVMetadataKeySpace(rawValue: "itsk"))
            
            if let data = genreItems1.first, let genreData = data.dataValue {
                let val = Int(genreData[1])
                let gen = genres[val - 1]
                genre = gen
            }
        }
        
        if (genre.isEmpty) {
            audioDict["Genre"] = ""
        }
        else {
            audioDict["Genre"] = genre
        }
        
        let composerItems = AVMetadataItem.metadataItems(from: metadata, withKey: "©wrt", keySpace: AVMetadataKeySpace(rawValue: "itsk"))
        if let data = composerItems.first, let composerString = data.stringValue {
            composer = composerString
            audioDict["Composer"] = composer
        } else {
            audioDict["Composer"] = ""
        }
        
        let durationTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(avasset.duration)
        let minutes = Int(durationTime / 60)
        let seconds = Int(durationTime.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60))
        let secs = String(format: "%02d", seconds)
        let audioDuration = "\(minutes):\(secs)"
        duration = audioDuration
        if (duration.isEmpty) {
            audioDict["Duration"] = ""
        } else {
            audioDict["Duration"] = duration
        }
        
        do {
            let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(audioDict)
            if let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) {
                return jsonString
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error converting dict to Json string: ", error)
        }
        
        return ""
    }
```

Comment: Is that also what happens when you record a video with your device?

Comment: I do not record anything...just reading songs from itunes such as ../Matthew Sweet/Girlfriend/03 Girlfriend.m4p. There is no metadata to read via AVFoundation.

Answer (score 0):

Reading M4P files works in one project but not another, so I am closing this as a permissions issue. Thanks!